# Dividing the non-zero elements in any array

Tags: python

How do I divide the numbers in any array ignoring the zero elements. For example, if I have an array of:

```
[1, 0 , 2, 0, 4, 0, 12]
```

I would like to have an printout of:

```
q1 = 2/1 = 2
q2 = 4/2 = 2
q3 = 12/4 = 3
```

Another example is that if I have an array of:

```
[1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 8]
```

I would want the results to be:

```
q1 = 4/1 = 4
q2 = 8/4 = 2
```

Comment: Please include your code, even if it produces index errors.

Comment: Are you dividing each element by a different number?

Comment: sounds like you want what is known as a right hand fold, or also known as `foldr` in functional languages

Comment: @nrbix dividing all the non-zero elements in order: i+1 / i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) you can create an iterator of non-zero values. Then simply divide each element with the previous one:

```py
l = [1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 12]
no_zeros = filter(None, l)

prev = next(no_zeros)
for cur in no_zeros:
    print(f"{cur}/{prev} = {cur//prev}")
    prev = cur
```

Prints out:

```
2/1 = 2
4/2 = 2
12/4 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter your input list to ignore 0s.

Then, you can obtain pairwise (i, i+1) tuples by zipping the original list with the tail of the list.

This will let you print the quotients in order.

```
nums = [1, 0 , 2, 0, 4, 0, 12]
non_zeros = [num for num in nums if num != 0]
for i, (divisor, dividend) in enumerate(zip(non_zeros, non_zeros[1:])):
    quotient = dividend / divisor
    print(f"q{i + 1}: {dividend}/{divisor} = {quotient}")
```

Comment: See @Tomerikoo 's answer - using generators is more memory efficient.